# New model in Spree extension: uninitialized constant Spree::MyClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm trying to create a new model in spree extension. I generated a model and it is in /spree_extension/app/models/my_class.rb:

```
module Spree
  class MyClass < Spree::Base
    belongs_to :product
  end
end
```

But when I start my application, there is no Spree::MyClass, I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::MyClass
```

I tried moving my_class.rb to "spree" directory, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact I created a table `my_class`.

Since I renamed it to `spree_my_class`, it works.

Comment: That's just because your model file is not in `models/spree/` subdir as advised in comments, but in root of one of models search path. I've many custom Spree extensions and all are named without *spree_* prefix.

Comment: @david-unric I tried putting it in different subdirs before I asked a question. Also I found a `spree.rb` file in my `/models` dir where I have this code: `def self.table_name_prefix 'spree_'`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you need to put your class into:

```
/spree_extension/app/models/spree/my_class.rb
```

As rails is always expecting to find classes inside file with the same name, inside folder that has the module name.

Comment: This doesn't help. Also tried to put class to this dir:


    /spree_extension/app/models/spree/my_class.rb

Comment: @vladzaets Placing into `<project_root>/app/models/spree/` or any other rubygems/bundler search paths with the same model's subdir and `my_class.rb` should work. What *exactly* is the full path to your extension ?

Comment: @david-unric full path of extension: `/Users/vladislavzaets/Desktop/projects/_spree/spree_extension`, full path to project: `/Users/vladislavzaets/Desktop/projects/mystore`, in projects Gemfile: `gem 'spree_extension', path: '../_spree/spree_extension'`